# Unable to create a flutter project: No option specified for the output directory error

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to create a new Flutter project. I tried ,

1.`flutter create` and

2. `flutter create --org com.domain.appname`

They both returned the following.

```
No option specified for the output directory.
Create a new Flutter project.

If run on a project that already exists, this will repair the project,
recreating any files that are missing.

Global options:
-h, --help                  Print this usage information.
-v, --verbose               Noisy logging, including all shell commands
                            executed.
                            If used with "--help", shows hidden options. If used
                            with "flutter doctor", shows additional diagnostic
                            information. (Use "-vv" to force verbose logging in
                            those cases.)
-d, --device-id             Target device id or name (prefixes allowed).
    --version               Reports the version of this tool.
    --suppress-analytics    Suppress analytics reporting when this command runs.

Usage: flutter create <output directory>
-h, --help                   Print this usage information.
    --[no-]pub               Whether to run "flutter pub get" after the project
                             has been created.
                             (defaults to on)
    --[no-]offline           When "flutter pub get" is run by the create
                             command, this indicates whether to run it in
                             offline mode or not. In offline mode, it will need
                             to have all dependencies already available in the
                             pub cache to succeed.
    --[no-]overwrite         When performing operations, overwrite existing
                             files.
    --description            The description to use for your new Flutter
                             project. This string ends up in the pubspec.yaml
                             file.
                             (defaults to "A new Flutter project.")
    --org                    The organization responsible for your new Flutter
                             project, in reverse domain name notation. This
                             string is used in Java package names and as prefix
                             in the iOS bundle identifier.
                             (defaults to "com.example")
    --project-name           The project name for this new Flutter project. This
                             must be a valid dart package name.
-i, --ios-language           The language to use for iOS-specific code, either
                             ObjectiveC (legacy) or Swift (recommended).
                             [objc, swift (default)]
-a, --android-language       The language to use for Android-specific code,
                             either Java (legacy) or Kotlin (recommended).
                             [java, kotlin (default)]
    --platforms              The platforms supported by this project. Platform
                             folders (e.g. android/) will be generated in the
                             target project. This argument only works when
                             "--template" is set to app or plugin. When adding
                             platforms to a plugin project, the pubspec.yaml
                             will be updated with the requested platform. Adding
                             desktop platforms requires the corresponding
                             desktop config setting to be enabled.
                             [ios (default), android (default), windows
                             (default), linux (default), macos (default), web
                             (default)]
-t, --template=<type>        Specify the type of project to create.

          [app]              (default) Generate a Flutter application.
          [module]           Generate a project to add a Flutter module to an
                             existing Android or iOS application.
          [package]          Generate a shareable Flutter project containing
                             only Dart code.
          [plugin]           Generate a shareable Flutter project containing an
                             API in Dart code with a platform-specific
                             implementation for Android, for iOS code, or for
                             both.

-s, --sample=<id>            Specifies the Flutter code sample to use as the
                             "main.dart" for an application. Implies
                             "--template=app". The value should be the sample ID
                             of the desired sample from the API documentation
                             website (http://docs.flutter.dev/). An example can
                             be found at:
                             https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChild
                             ScrollView-class.html
    --list-samples=<path>    Specifies a JSON output file for a listing of
                             Flutter code samples that can be created with
                             "--sample".

Run "flutter help" to see global options.
```

Below is my `flutter doctor` output.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-arm, locale
    en-LK)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.59.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

I am using MacBook Pro M1 Chip laptop, is that helps.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I was very stupid to raise a simple question, maybe I was just over tired working long hours. Anyway, I made a mistake and here is the answr.

`flutter create --org com.domain appname`

notice the space between the `appname` and `com.domain`

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to add the output directory. You need to place that before the --org call:

> flutter create . --org....

The . is the current directory, or specify one using

> C:/Users/...path to your directory

Comment: sorry, this is not working either. it says `multiple output directories specified`. Maybe you can post the full command to make sure error proof?

Comment: Also this mentioning output directory is not something I have done before, even though i have developed many flutter apps.

Comment: Using the **dot .**  to specify the current directory worked for me
flutter create .  --platforms=windows,macos,linux  --org com.packagname

Although, I was only able to add support for macos; given it's my current OS

Answer (score 0):

try: flutter create --org com.domain appname in terminal.
Of course you can change "appname" into the file name you want.